# Ctrl+Z no works and Press Shift+R in sculpt mode jump to object mode

Tags: modeling

I have 2 Questions. First, when I press ctrl+Z, my object doesn't undo to last step except undo to a very early step. second, When I press Shift+R in sculpt mode the object jump to object mode.

Comment: Since @moonboots answered the question about `Shift`+`R`, would you please edit out the `Ctrl`+`Z` part and make it a new question? I will gladly answer it, but it is preferable on this site that different problems are asked and answered separately.

Answer (score 0):

You should only ask one question. <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> doesn't work anymore in the latest versions, it's <kbd>R</kbd> to set the remesh size, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to apply the remesh.